# Как парсить вакансии с API Зарплата.ру в R

Tags: json, парсер, api, r

Есть API джоб-сайта "Зарплата.ру"

```
https://api.zp.ru/v1/
```

Как парсить вакансии в R с пакетом jsonlite? То есть, как именно нужно обратиться? К примеру, через API HeadHunter это корректно делается так:

```
  string <-"https://api.hh.ru/vacancies?text=\"'machine+learning\"&page="
for (pageNum in 0:5){ # Всего страниц
  data <- fromJSON(paste0(string,  pageNum))
  vacanciesdf <- rbind(vacanciesdf, data.frame(
    data$items$area$name, # Город
    data$items$salary$currency, # Валюта
    data$items$salary$from, # Минимальная оплата
    data$items$employer$name, # Название компании
    data$items$name,#Название должности
    data$items$snippet$requirement)) # Требуемые навыки
  print(paste0("Upload pages:", pageNum + 1))
  Sys.sleep(3)
}
```

Как решить аналогичную задачу через API "Зарплата.ру" чтобы была возможность задать ключевое слово и рассортировать данные по столбцам data.frame?

Answer (score 1):

Пример кода для выполнения запроса с использованием пакета `crul`.

```
# HHTP клиент
cl <- crul::HttpClient$new(url = "https://api.zp.ru")
# Запрос к API
resp <- cl$get(path = "v1/vacancies",
               query = list(scope = "public", q = "machine+learning", limit = 100L))
# Парсинг ответа
ans <- jsonlite::fromJSON(resp$parse(encoding = "UTF-8"))
# Количество записей в результате выдачи
cat(ans$metadata$resultset$count)
#> 2
# Извлекаем необходимые поля
res <- ans$vacancies
data.frame(
    header = res$header,
    published_at = as.Date(res$publication$published_at),
    salary = res$salary,
    education = res$education$title,
    experience_length = res$experience_length$title,
    schedule = res$schedule$title,
    working_type = res$working_type$title,
    requirements = res$requirements,
    url = paste0("https://www.zp.ru", res$url),
    company = res$company$title,
    address = paste(res$address$city$title, res$address$street, res$address$building)
)
#>                          header published_at     salary education
#> 1 Senior, Middle Data scientist   2017-12-08 договорная    высшее
#> 2         Junior Data scientist   2017-12-08 договорная    высшее
#>   experience_length      schedule     working_type
#> 1           3-5 лет гибкий график полная занятость
#> 2         без опыта гибкий график полная занятость
#>                                                requirements
#> 1 Высшее образование, стаж работы 3-5 лет, полная занятость
#> 2           Высшее образование, без опыта, полная занятость
#>                                                                   url
#> 1 https://www.zp.ru/vacancy/Senior_Middle_Data_scientist?id=139080429
#> 2        https://www.zp.ru/vacancy/Junior_Data_scientist?id=139080474
#>      company                    address
#> 1 СКБ Контур Екатеринбург Малопрудная 5
#> 2 СКБ Контур Екатеринбург Малопрудная 5
```

Для выгрузки всех результатов в случае если их больше 100, необходимо использовать параметр `offset`.

Описание полей возвращаемого результата приведено в документации по API.

При необходимости можно извлекать только нужные поля при помощи параметра `fields`. Например:

```
query = list(scope = "public",
             q = "machine+learning", limit = 100L,
             fields = "header,company.title")
```

Пример постраничной выгрузки:

```
#' @title Функция для выгрузки вакансий с сайта zp.ru
#' @param cl HTTP клиент. Создаётся при помощи `crul::HttpClient`.
#' @param query Строка, содержащая запрос.
#' @param limit Целое число от 1 до 100, определяющее количество результатов.
#' @return data.frame с результатами запроса
fetch_vacancies <- function(cl, query) {
  limit <- 100L
  q <- list(
    scope = "public",
    q = query,
    limit = limit
  )
  fetch_data <- function(query) {
    # Запрос к API
    resp <- cl$get(path = "v1/vacancies", query = query)
    # Проверка статуса ответа
    resp$raise_for_status()
    # Парсинг ответа
    jsonlite::fromJSON(resp$parse(encoding = "UTF-8"))
  }
  extract_data <- function(data) {
    res <- data$vacancies
    data.frame(
      header = res$header,
      published_at = res$publication$published_at,
      salary = res$salary,
      education = res$education$title,
      experience_length = res$experience_length$title,
      schedule = res$schedule$title,
      working_type = res$working_type$title,
      requirements = res$requirements,
      url = paste0("https://www.zp.ru", res$url),
      company = res$company$title,
      address = paste(res$address$city$title, res$address$street, res$address$building)
    )
  }
  ans <- fetch_data(q)
  res <- extract_data(ans)
  # Орабатываем случай, если результатов больше 100
  if (ans$metadata$resultset$count > limit) {
    e <- new.env()
    # Доабвляем уже полученные данные
    e[["0"]] <- res
    offset <- 101L
    count <- ans$metadata$resultset$count
    # Повторяем запросы и парсинг со смещением в 100
    while (offset < count) {
      q$offset <- offset
      res <- extract_data(fetch_data(q))
      e[[as.character(offset)]] <- res
      # Предотвращаем спам запросов
      Sys.sleep(0.4)
      # Выводим сообщение
      cat("\rFetch page ", (offset - 1L) / 100L)
      offset <- offset + 100L
    }
    # Собираем все результаты
    res <- do.call(rbind, as.list(e))
  }
  # Добавляем обработанный запрос в атрибуты рзультата
  attr(res, "query") <- ans$metadata$query$searched_q
  return(res)
}

# HHTP клиент
cl <- crul::HttpClient$new(url = "https://api.zp.ru")
query <- "Аналитик"
res <- fetch_vacancies(cl, query)
```

Comment: Правильно ли понимаю, что таким образом мы спарсили конкретные навыки, но как через них вывести резюме в датафрейм с разбивкой по признакам?

Comment: В ответе приведён пример работы с API сайта zp.ru. Если хотите получить более конкретный ответ, задавайте более конкретный вопрос со ссылками на страницы документации по API. Какую конкретно информацию вы хотите получить через API и в каком формате сохранить, из вопроса не понятно. Как обратиться к API приведено в моём ответе.

Comment: Да, за код благодарен! Опробовал. Вопрос конкретный, как его модифицировать на выгрузку вакансий со всеми данными по столбцам по этой вакансии (то есть: з/п, город, страна, требования ну и т.д.). На Hh.ru это понятно, в приведенном коде это видно, а вот с Zp.ru, как-то не совсем очевидно

Comment: Добавил пример извлечения полей для вакансий.

Comment: Огромная благодарность, @Artem Klevtsov! Так ведь и не подумаешь, что на stakoverflow.com тебе поможет твой студенческий преподаватель :)

Comment: А существует ли какой-то способ преодоления лимита в 100 строк? Конечно попробовал написать 200, но парсит всё равно только 100.

Comment: Этот лимит в самом API (см. документацию). Преодолевается циклом (или аналогичной конструкцией) с изменением параметра `offset`.

Comment: Добавил пример выгрузки со смещением (возможно нужна отладка).